# Execute Perl with PHP and redirect to new site

Tags: php, perl

Basically i want to continously run a longer Perl-Script in the background and keep on running even after i redirect the user to a different page

php

```
<?php
$result = exec("perl test.pl");
echo $result;

header("Location: newpage.php") ;
?>
```

perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

sleep(1000000);
print "Done";
```

I read about fork() in php but how i understood it it just runs 2 scripts simoultaniously but i can't figure out how to work with redirection/header() in php. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

PHP exec will wait until the execution of the called program is finished, before processing the next line, unless you use "&" at the end of the string to run the program in background.

```
<?php
$result = exec("perl test.pl &");
echo $result;

header("Location: newpage.php") ;
?>
```

Alternatively, you could consider adding a crono event to continuously run the exec, depending on what it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, which we've used, is to use a job queue of some sort, such as beanstalk or redis (technically, I don't think redis is a job queue, but its pub/sub model looks like it can be used as such, depending on your needs).

The php code would post the job to be run, an always-running executable (perl or whatever) would be running in the background, listening for jobs, and then start a job as its own child, rather than a child of your php process, when a job came through.  Depending on your needs, the job could post its status, including final results, either in a cache on the file system or in a database, such as mysql or redis, so that if your end user clicks on a page to view the job status, it's available.

It's more complex, but handles more edge cases.  The downside is that if your web site is on a shared server, the ISP may not like that always-running job server, or the beanstalk/redis daemons.  This works better if you have your own VM to work with.